# php dynamic array checking

Tags: php

Hy,

I have a multidimensional array with sub arrays and stuff like this :

```
 [21] => Array
        (
            [80] =>
            [83] =>
            [A4] => Array
                (
                    [80] =>
                )

            [85] =>
            [A6] => Array
                (
                    [80] =>
                )

            [87] =>
            [88] =>
            [A9] => Array
                (
                    [A0] => Array
                        (
                            [80] =>
                        )

                )

            [8B] =>
            [AC] => Array
                (
                    [30] => Array
                        (
                            [81] =>
                            [82] =>
                            [83] =>
                            [84] =>
                            [85] =>
                            [86] =>
                            [88] =>
                        )

                )

            [8D] =>
            [8E] =>
            [8F] =>
            [91] =>
            [92] =>
            [93] =>
            [94] =>
            [9B] =>
            [96] =>
            [97] =>
            [9D] =>
        )
```

I want to create a function to pass a level to check array_keys_exist

If the level is `0` then it should `array_keys_exist($array['21']);`
If the level is `1` then is should `array_keys_exist($array['21'][])` but the problem is I cannot use `$array[21][]` and only ckech the `80,80,A0 and 30`.

Is this possible ?

Thank you

Comment: sounds confusing, what do you mean by level 0/1?

Comment: if level is 1 i want to check if a given key exist in $array[21][] keys (in this case only : `80 , 80 , A0 and 30 `) - normaly it would be `array_keys_exist($array[21][A4]) ... $array[21][A6] ... $array[21][A9] ... $array[21][AC]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function array_key_exists_recursive($key, $array, $levelsToCheck = 0) {
  if (array_key_exists($key, $array) {
    return true;
  }
  if($levelsToCheck > 0) {
    foreach($array as $entry) {
      if(is_array($entry) && 
         array_key_exists_recursive(
            $key, 
            $entry, 
            $levelsToCheck - 1
         )
      ) {
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Or, if you only want to check all arrays at a given depth:

```
function array_key_exists_at_depth($key, $array, $depth = 0) {
  if ($depth <= 0) {
    return array_key_exists($key, $array);
  }
  foreach($array as $entry) {
    if(is_array($entry) && 
       array_key_exists_at_depth (
          $key, 
          $entry, 
          $depth - 1
       )
    ) {
        return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```